# How to classify the combination of two string values should be the same independent or order

Tags: sequence-analysis

I have data for Airline flights that include both origin and destination (airports). So for example, I  have one flight that goes from Chicago to New York:
ORD-JFK; and a flight from New York to Chicago: JFK-ORD. I don't care the direction of the flight, I would like to create an index that tells me that those two flights are in the same airport-pair. Origin and Destination are two different vectors (and yeah, I can create a single vector with JFKORD or ORDJFK), but how to I tell R that those two should be classified as the same?
I have about 12000 combinations of origin as destination, which means I should only have about 6000 airport pairs. Is there a way I could program that?

Comment: I dont see a statistical question in here, what is it?